# Gollum wiki not starting

Tags: gollum-wiki

I've been trying to get Gollum-wiki up and going but I keep getting an error about 'library not load' Here is what error Im getting for when I try to start it up:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.3/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicudata.55.1.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.3/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

Just updated brew and had the same issue, but reinstalling gem with:

```
gem install charlock_holmes
```

Solved my pain :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the icu4c package. NB This is not a ruby gem

Hopefully you are using Homebrew, and it's just a question of running

`brew install icu4c`

Handy tip. If you upgrade icu4c then Gollum can break. Reinstalling the `charlock_holmes` gem seems to fix this.